# Do Desktop apps need HTTP preflight requests?

Tags: http, web-applications, cors, desktop-application, preflight

I'm developing an app that needs to get info from a third party API. I've been developing it to be a web application with Vuejs. For the requests I tried to use axios, jquery and the fetch API, but I'm having trouble with the preflight requests, it seems that the API is not treating the OPTIONS requests properly and it throws me a 405 error (I made a GET request on the same url through Postman and it worked normally and I also edited a OPTIONS request on firefox network panel to become a GET request and it returned a 200 status).
Now I'm thinking of abandon the idea of the web application and work it as a desktop application, but I need to know if the preflight requests are going to be a default behavior in this kind of app too.
Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, CORS preflight requests are made by browsers, and are necessary due to the browser security model. They would not be used by a desktop application.

You can easily test this with curl, postman, etc. It sounds like you tried this, but the details you've described are off. Don't change anything to `GET`. Use the actual request you're trying to make, but do it outside the browser context. If the API responds appropriately then it should work in a desktop application.

Comment: Thanks, Actually the request I was trying to make was a GET one. I already tested it in postman too. So thanks for helping! =)

Comment: @Akelesis: But `GET` requests never trigger preflights. So I'm not sure why you were worrying about that for a `GET` request. And note that the browser will take care of the preflight for you, you never have to craft the `OPTIONS` request yourself.

Comment: Yes, and the problem is just that... I have a cross origin GET request with custom headers, when I use postman to contact the API it goes smoothly, but when I try it through the browser it triggers a OPTIONS request and it seems that URL cannot deal with a request of this kind and it gives me a 405 error. At first I thought it would be my fault by providing wrong headers, then I tested in firefox editing the type of the request to GET and resend it and it was accepted. So, I concluded it was a problem with the preflight request from the browser.